# Green lights in ocean

Tags: civilization-5

While playing Civ 5, I occasionally see these green things in the sea:

[image]

Is this just a bug like the red dots that sometimes show up on land, or is this some kind of easter egg or resource?

Comment: Not something I've ever seen before, and I get the little red blobs a lot

Comment: Looks like a graphics glitch: http://forums.civfanatics.com/showthread.php?t=388639

Comment: Could that be water-based uranium, maybe?

Comment: It's hinting to you that there is a nuclear submarine in the area :)

Comment: On mine it shot out of the sky after the manhattan experiment

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I get the same thing but mine are blackish/purplish I think it has something to do with the GPU which cause the certain spots on the water effect to glitch up. So it can be categorized as a bug :) nothing major to worry about.